# Performing CRUD operation on massive data attained from a Web-Service

Tags: java, web-services, spring

I am working on a project that maintains a **list of user and their site** in a DB table. The user column contains e-mail addresses of the users and corresponding entry contains the website they own. Something like this:

```
        dbTable
    ==================================
    email       | website
    ----------------------------------
    user1@abc.com   | http://xyz.com
    user2@abc.com   | http://asd.com
    user2@abc.com   | http://qwerty.com
    user3@abc.com   | http://asdfg.com
    .
    .
```

The table contains thousands of rows and it is to be populated and **maintained as per a Web Service**. With the help of JAX-B, I unmarshalled the WS and inserted the data on the first run. Now, this table is to be updated as per the web service. i.e. **users/websites should be updated or deleted according to the data received from the web service**.

My initial idea was to make an ID w.r.t email+website and store it as a third entry in the table and for future CRUD operations I would just refer to this ID. However, my superior advised against coding the whole batch update process by self and use any framework features, `my project uses Spring`, for batch CRUD operations or maybe exploit feature provided by the database, `POSTGRESQL`. **Is there any such feature provided in Spring that I can use to perform batch updates on the db?** Any ideas? Please advice.

Comment: ibatis orm provides a nice batch update feature.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at [Hibernate](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html). This [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) integrates pretty well with Spring and can do [batch operations](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html). You can take a look [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html) for something similar to what you need to do.

Information [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html) should point you in the right direction as to setting up Hibernate for PostgreSQL.